# Instantiating the base class member by creating the object in the derived class Method

Tags: c#

when i am trying to instantiate the base class member by creating an object in the derived class method it should be accessed by c.Id instead getting an error

```
public class RetailCust : Customer
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.id=102 //getting an error
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    protected int id = 100;
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of `Customer`? `RetailCust` has normal access to `id`

Comment: `c.id = 102` should be `this.id = 102;` or `base.id = 102;`

Comment: "Getting an error" doesn't tell us anything. Please post the error stack.

Answer (score 1):

Deriving from the class provides you access to the `protected` members of the parent, true. But creating instance of the parent class, does not grant you any access to `private` or `protected` members of that instance. Basically, like any other class you can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you'd want is:

```
public class RetailCust : Customer
{
  public void Print()
  {
    this.id = 102;
  }
}
```

There's no need to instantiate a Customer object inside print as it looks like what you're trying to do is set the current RetailCust object to have an ID of 102?

Edit/Update:
The reason why there's no reason to instantiate a `Customer` object is that you ARE a `Customer` object (just a more specific type of `RetailCust`).  So just refer to any property the `Customer` class has by using `this` or `base` (if you override it and want to differentiate between this and base).

Comment: `c.id` doesn't refer to anything (and won't compile)

Comment: Sorry, I changed c to this.  That should compile.